# How to look up settings of pre-defined plotting themes (e.g. ggplot, yarrr)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, themes

In R, how can I look up the settings of pre-defined themes for plotting?
Specifically, I am using the yarrr package to create a pirateplot of my data. 
This function comes with a number of predefined themes: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/yarrr/vignettes/pirateplot.html
How can I see what the settings are of the themes? That would help me better understand the parameters and allow me to adjust the plots as I need them.

Is there a general command that would also work for ggplot? (I used the ggplot tag because I could not add yarrr as tag, by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of each theme in the pirateplot package can be found inside the `pirateplot_function.R`, in the source code.

Take a look at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/ndphillips/yarrr/blob/master/R/pirateplot_function.R) - the themes start at line 833.

For ggplot you could do the same, or call the function without the `()`, e.g. `theme_classic` gives you

```
function (base_size = 11, base_family = "", base_line_size = base_size/22, 
    base_rect_size = base_size/22) 
{
    theme_bw(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family, 
        base_line_size = base_line_size, base_rect_size = base_rect_size) %+replace% 
        theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", 
                size = rel(1)), legend.key = element_blank(), 
            strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", 
                colour = "black", size = rel(2)), complete = TRUE)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000018a82e33cf0>
<environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

Which gives you a lot of unnecessary information, but also shows you the code in that function. In RStudio, you can use `View(theme_classic)` to see it in the editor window instead of outputting to console.